# "Local Area Connection" doesn't have a valid IP config

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, internet-connection

I’ve been trying to help my father regain his connection that abruptly ceased working. He runs his connection through an intermediary router that he uses as a switch; if that is important at all. we’ve tried looking through the solutions on many, MANY online solutions listed and looked through a number of tech sites similar to this.

I’ve come to the conclusion that the problem must be awfully specific so I figured I should post the results of `ipconfig /all` here to see if any folks savvier than us with tech happen to know a solution to what seems a rather specific problem. We’ve also tried repair programs such as Tweaking etc… So far nothing has worked, so here is the info:

Windows IP Configuration

- **Host Name:** Pierre-PC
- **Primary Dns Suffix:**
- **Node Type:** Hybrid
- **IP Routing Enabled:** No
- **Wins Proxy Enabled:** No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection

- **Connection-specific DNS Suffix:**
- **Description:** Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- **Physical Address:** 00-E0-4C-8D-7C-8F
- **DHCP Enabled:** Yes
- **Autoconfiguration Enabled:** Yes
- **Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address:** 169.254.111.240 (Preferred)
- **Subnet:** 255.255.0.0
- **Default Gateway:**
- **NetBIOS over Tcpip:** Enabled

Tunnel adapter `isatap.{22FBB81D-1D71-4D76-8766-0E5362D1F50D}`:

- **Media State:** Media Disconnected
- **Connection-specific DNS Suffix:**
- **Description:** Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
- **Physical Address:** 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
- **DHCP Enabled:** No
- **Autoconfiguration Enabled:** Yes

Edit: We're using a DSL-2750 D-Link as a primary Router, and a SP0005 BENQ switch to connect to my father's PC which is the only one displaying this problem. All three of us are connected to the D-Link but only my father uses the switch as an intermediary, and yes I believe the Router is being used as the DHCP server. Our ISP is Afrihost, as we're located in South Africa.

We also have already tried ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew as well as a few other commands, disabling ipv6 and re-enabling it later, using Tweaking, and even going as far as using a system restore. None of these have worked so far. Is there any other information I have left out that would be helpful?

Double Edit: We've managed to solve the problem by disconnecting the switch, we don't know why it was an issue but we're happy with the result all the same. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Did you try "ipconfig /release" and "ipconfig /renew"? Also, is the router/switch working as a DHCP server? (e.g it's deciding the IP addresses for all devices connected to it)

Comment: Quick comment here: "Addresses in the range 169.254.0.0 to 169.254.255.255 are used automatically by most network devices when they are configured to use IP, do not have a static IP Address assigned and are unable to obtain an IP address using DHCP.

This traffic is intended to be confined to the local network, so the administrator of the local network should look for misconfigured hosts. Some ISPs inadvertently also permit this traffic, so you may also want to contact your ISP. This is documented in RFC 6890." from https://www.iana.org/help/abuse-answers

Comment: OP here, just removed the switch from the equation and directly connected to the D-Link instead after a nightmarish session of trial and error troubleshooting. Thanks to everyone who posted help and advice, although we never narrowed down exactly what the problem was aside from it being directly to the switch which never seemed to be a problem beforehand. We really should have tried this earlier, but at least the problem has been dealt with, thanks everyone!

Comment: @Leathe or PierreHLP should post the solution as an answer and then LierreHLP can mark it as answered.

Comment: Out of curiousity @PierreHLP, did the local network IP change to a 192.168.1.0 range (or another) or stay as a 169.254.0.0 range? Oh, and also, do you now have a default gateway?

Comment: @PierreHLP - You should add that as an answer to the question then :). We do things differently here, we don't add 'Solved' and such to the question, answers are kept separate to the question body :)